# simply google maps rotate custom marker jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jsfiddle

I get my all latitude and longitude values in firebase and display all values in my google map, Its moving also good.

My problem is my car images  can not rotate the drivers direction. My self load svg image also.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function() {

        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'json',
                url: 'google-ajax.php',
                cache: false,
                data: $('#dvMap').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var markers = data;

                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                        zoom: 6,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    var lat_lng = new Array();

                    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {


                        var data = markers[i]
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                        lat_lng.push(myLatlng);


                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: map,
                            title: data.title,
                            icon: {
                                url: "http://localhost/uberx/admin/images/carnew.svg"
                            }

                            //icon:"http://localhost/uberx/admin/images/carnew.svg"


                        });

                        latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                        (function(marker, data) {
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                            });
                        })(marker, data);
                    }
                    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
                    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);


                }
            });

        }, 5000);
    }


    /*$(document).ready(function(){

    onload(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is Ready


    });

    //Refresh auto_load() function after 10000 milliseconds
    setInterval(onload,10000);*/
</script>
```

Comment: please explain "can not rotate the drivers direction" - do you mean that the icon is to be orientated with the direction of travel? There is nothing in the code above that appears to attempt this - and to do so would require some sort of GPS telemetry data that gives the `bearing` of the `driver`

Comment: the icon is to be orientated with the direction of travel?   Yes

Comment: telemetry data?? How is your map to know anything of the driver and where he/she is or where they are going or in which direction?

Comment: see this link   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dnW5N7GcuHnS_D85G9-KCpeS3B22gsHg/view

Comment: ok - i watched that video 3 times and am still no clearer so please answer - How are you getting the realtime position (lat,lng) of the car and it's bearing?

Comment: My working now app in web services. So app side updated lat long value in fire base ,And i getted lat long values in fire base

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163378/discussion-between-meena-narayanan-and-ramraider).